# Dynamically attach EventListner to link using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, addeventlistener, sweetalert2, removeeventlistener

The following code in injected to a wordpress page through `functions.php`.
I am using `SweetAlert2` to launch a popup window that displays consent for `TOS`.
I am trying to dynamically attach an `eventListner` to the link launching that popup window.
When page is first loaded, `monthly` in initialized (button is `active`), but once the `oneTime` button is clicked, I wish to re-attach the `eventListener` to the link on that form (`show_iframe_2`).
Somehow the code behaves strange, at first round it doesn't launch the popup on the `oneTime` button, but after clicking the link and going back and forth between the 2 forms, it will...
Any ideas how to achieve the task?

```
window.onload = function () {
  const oneTime = document.getElementById("show_iframe_2");
  const monthly = document.getElementById("show_iframe_1");
  // these are on monthly form elements
  let popLink = document.getElementById("privacyLink");
  let consentCheckBox = document.getElementById("field_68823bb");
  updatePopLink(popLink, consentCheckBox);

  async function updatePopLink(link, checkBox) {
    if (popLink) {
      popLink.removeEventListener("click", launchPopUp);
    }
    popLink = link;
    consentCheckBox = checkBox;
    await popLink.addEventListener("click", launchPopUp);
  }
  function launchPopUp() {
    fetch("https://privacy-and-tos-page/")
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((text) => {
        // Parse the response text as an HTML document
        let parser = new DOMParser();
        let doc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");

        // Select the element by its id
        let element = doc.getElementById("main");

        // Get the innerHTML of the selected element
        let html = element.innerHTML;

        Swal.fire({
          title: "",
          html: html,
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
          cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
          confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
          width: 1200,
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
            consentCheckBox.checked = true;
          } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
            consentCheckBox.checked = false;
          }
        });
      });
  }

  oneTime.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    popLink = document.getElementById("privacyLink");
    consentCheckBox = document.getElementById("field_6a9f758");
    updatePopLink(popLink, consentCheckBox);
  });
  monthly.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    popLink = document.getElementById("linkId");
    consentCheckBox = document.getElementById("field_68823bb");
    updatePopLink(popLink, consentCheckBox);
  });
};
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot `let` for `popLink` at bottom. Should be `let popLink = ...`

Comment: @ФаридАхмедов that’s not it, `let` it used higher up in scope so it’s not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't find a solution, I simply did the following:

```
window.onload = (event) => {
    let popLinkMonthly = document.getElementById("privacyLink");
    let consetCkBoxMonthly = document.getElementById("field_68823bb");
    let popLinkOneTime = document.getElementById("linkId");
    let consetCkBoxOneTime = document.getElementById("field_68823bb");
        popLinkMonthly.addEventListener('click', function(){

          fetch("https://some-url/")
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(text => {
            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let doc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");

            let element = doc.getElementById("main");
            let html = element.innerHTML;

            Swal.fire({
                title: '',
                html: html,
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                width: 1200,
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    consetCkBoxMonthly.checked = true;
                } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
                    consetCkBoxMonthly.checked = false;
                }
            });
        })                  
    });

        popLinkOneTime.addEventListener('click', function(){

            fetch("https://some-url/")
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
                let parser = new DOMParser();
                let doc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");

                let element = doc.getElementById("main");

                let html = element.innerHTML;

                    Swal.fire({
                        title: '',
                        html: html,
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
                        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                        width: 1200,
                    }).then((result) => {
                        if (result.value) {
                            consetCkBoxOneTime.checked = true;
                        } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
                            consetCkBoxOneTime.checked = false;
                        }
                    });
                })                  
            });
        }
```